# Using periodic boundary conditions for disk region in polar coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am trying to find the eigen values/functions of laplace operator in polar coordinates `r`, `fi` in disk region. In cartesian coordinates: `(NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 6])`. In polar coordinates angle variabe should sutisfy periodic b.c. and radial shoud sutisfy dirichlet. The code I am working on looks like:

```
NDEigensystem[
 {
  -(D[y[r, fi], {fi, 2}]/r^2) - 1/r D[r*D[y[r, fi], r], r], (* equation *)
    DirichletCondition[y[r, fi] == 0, r == 1.],
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[y[r, fi], fi == 2 Pi, Function[fi, fi - 2 Pi]
  },

 y[r, fi],
 {r, 0, 1}, {fi, 0, 2 Pi},
 3]
```

The problem is with setting following periodic condition `y(r,fi+2 Pi) = y(r,fi)` the way I did:  `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[y[r, fi], fi == 2 Pi, Function[fi, fi - 2 Pi]]`. Is it possibe to do such "mixing" of boundary condition, and if yes how exacly should I specify them?

I will appreciate any help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please add the definition of `rmax` to the question.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with 'mixing'?

Comment: ```rmax``` was a typo , its the same 1. "Mixing" is to use Dirichlet b.c. for ```r``` and periodic for ```fi``` varibles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some trial and error process I finally made this work:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-(D[y[r, fi], {fi, 2}]/r^2) - 
     1/r D[r*D[y[r, fi], r], r],
    DirichletCondition[y[r, fi] == 0, r == 1 && 0 < fi <= 2 * Pi],
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[y[r, fi], fi == 0, 
     TranslationTransform[{0, 2 *Pi}]]
    },
   y[r, fi], {r, 0, 1}, {fi, 0, 2 * Pi},
   5
   ];
vals
```

(* {5.78319, 14.684, 14.684, 26.3764, 30.4756} *)

which are the eigenvalues of the Laplace operator in a unit disk:

```
Sort@Flatten@Table[(N@BesselJZero[i, j])^2, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Great. Would you mind if I added this example to the documentation of `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`?

Comment: Sure with great pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

The `DirichletCondition` overlaps with the periodic boundary condition (See the [Issues Section](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicBoundaryCondition.html))

You can use:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-(D[y[r, fi], {fi, 2}]/r^2) - 
     1/r D[r*D[y[r, fi], r], r],
    DirichletCondition[y[r, fi] == 0, 
     r == 1 && (fi != 0 && fi != 2 \[Pi])], 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[y[r, fi], fi == 2 \[Pi], 
     Function[fi, fi + 2 Pi]]}, y[r, fi], {r, 0, 1}, {fi, 0, 2 Pi}, 3];
vals
{5.9417694867356845`, 10.845294000815311`, 15.731501290360747`}
```

Comment: I`m sorry that I forgot to mention, but I would like to obtain the results the same as here ```NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 6]``` the eigenvalues shuld be expressed with ```BesselJZero``` like ```Sort@Flatten@Table[(N@BesselJZero[i, j])^2, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 1, 3}]```

Comment: @DavidBaghdasaryan, How does that relate to the question? Could you update the question? Why would you expect that a region with a periodic bc has the same eigenvalues as one with all Dirichlet conditions?

Comment: Sure I will update it, I just want to solve the disk problem (```NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 6]```) in polar coordinates in polar coorfinates angle variabe should sutisfy periodic b.c. and radial shoud sutisfy dirichlet.

Comment: @DavidBaghdasaryan, I see. If you think it helps I can delete my answer.

Comment: No, no there is no need. Thank you @user21, your answer was helpful for finding the solution.